# How does human body keep track of its age?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism

How does the human body knows that it's time for a event that happens around a certain age like puberty or something that's periodic like menstruation or gestation time of 9 months?

Please note I'm NOT talking about day-night biological clock .

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by 'how does the body know'.

Comment: this is still a very active are of study, the field is called chronobiology. 

Epigenetic clocks which may be longest, there are several Horvaths being the most famous and is based on the DNA methylation. I don't know the details of how it functions however.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as written now is broad and shows none of your own research. If you can edit to narrow down (e.g. only menstruation) and include some of your own research (what you found when reading about it), I'd happily remove my close vote and take a stab at the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh it's quite clear that it means how does human body triggers certain functions at certain age or period

Comment: @anongoodnurse I did search but nearly all result ended up on biological clock that regulates sleep. And that's not what I am searching for so I ended up posting a targeted question on SE

Comment: @anongoodnurse same here, also voting to close.

Comment: @user1062760 Please do not post such accusatory comments. What is there to be political about? There is no logic in favouring a certain user/group of users and discriminating against others. We don't even know anyone here in person. Posts are voted upon, not the users. Instead of taking things personally, why don't you consider the advice of experienced users and edit your post accordingly. Your question is interesting and others have said it too. However, it is also very broad. One can write a book or a big review on this topic. SE is not designed to handle questions like this. Pls understand

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't always. Some people have an undistorted slown down aging. Jyoti Amge is over 18 and looks like an undistorted little girl. Yesterday, I saw a TV show that showed a 22 year old who looked like an undistorted 8 year old girl. There are also people who have distorted aging. People with progeria look like a distorted older person. I think nodoby has an undistorted sped up aging. Gabby Williams looked like a distorted toddler when she was 12. Nicky freeman from https://thewest.com.au/news/australia/forty-year-old-trapped-in-childs-body-ng-ya-220462 has a distorted bone structure of a ten year old boy and is all wrinkly. The girl in the YouTube video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoBetcKAxII&t=96s has the undistorted bond structure of a 13 year old girl and is all wrinkly.